# How to derive the bound formula of hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The bound formula is:

$$H(M,N,n,k) \leq (( \frac{p}{p+t} )^{p+t} (\frac{1-p}{1-p-t})^{1-p-t})^n$$

So how to proof it?

Some papers discuss it:
[this one](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~kluh/thesis/kluh-2011-prop.pdf),
[that one](http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/professional/hypergeometric.pdf).

They say the proof is in the following paper:
The tail of the hypergeometric distribution. Discrete Mathematics

But I can not find the online version.

Comment: The paper is online here, but you need a university subscription. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(79)90084-0

Comment: Please don't post the same questions (more or less) simultaneously here and on MathOverflow. I suggest the following procedure: Ask here first and if you didn't get any helpful answer in a few *days* you might consider asking on MathOverflow. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55402/

Comment: Also you have the MR entry http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0534946

Comment: I'm sending you the paper per email, check your spam folder in case it isn't there in a few minutes. @Willie: I'm notifying you in order to avoid double action.

Comment: That, plus the fact that the inequality is a straightforward consequence of the usual exponential inequalities applied to sums of random variables. That is, coming back to the *physical* interpretation of the hypergeometric distribution, one considers $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where $X_i$ is Bernoulli and $X_i=1$ iff the ball drawn at time $i$ is white. The only twist here is that the $X_i$s are not independent. Fortunately, they are *negatively correlated*, hence the upper bound one would get by assuming independence is still valid.

Comment: @Didier: Ah, that clarifies a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Didier: Could you explain why when the random variable is negatively correlated, the independence assumption is still valid.

Comment: @Fan: That would be absurd and is not what I wrote. Rather, for every negatively correlated $U$ and $V$, $E(UV)\le E(U)E(V)$. (And if you merely look at the definition, you will see that it is meaningless to say that a random variable is negatively correlated, on its own, all alone...)

Comment: @Didier Thank you for your explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered to the satisfaction of the OP in the comments.